# How can I move view after pushing navigation controller?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, viewcontroller

I got viewcontroller with navigation bar. I move from it to another VC with pushViewcontroller.

Destination viewController has view with data writing in code. My navigation controller is closes part of my view. How can I shift my view's data bellow inserting navigation VC?

Comment: Could you possibly post some sample code please?

Comment: I need that my view starting not from 0.0 point, because navigation controller hide 0.0 point by yourself

Comment: I have no instance of this view. I use default ViewControllers view

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use (void)prepareforSegue

**First create a property in your next view controller, for this example I'm calling it ViewData.**

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"Your Identifier])
{

YourNextViewController *vc = (YourNextViewController*)segue.destinationViewController;
  [vc setViewData: @"Whatever data"];

}
```